# Очередь загрузки файлов на сайт

Tags: php, laravel

вопрос следующий: сайт (пишу на laravel) предусматривает функционал загрузки файлов (по одному файлу за запрос), как организовать очередь загрузки?

т.е. поступает несколько запросов (от нескольких пользователей) на загрузку и загружаемые файлы бросаются в очередь и валяются во вкладке "входящие", а загруженные и обработанные файлы бросаются во вкладку "загруженные".

Answer (score 1):

Создаете [работу](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#generating-job-classes) для каждого файла в определенную очередь, которая их будет обрабатывать. Если нужно обрабатывать строго в очереди, то запускаете очередь только с одним обработчиком (рабочим процессом).

```
class ProcessUploadedFile implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $file;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  string $file
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Обрабатываете файл и перемещаете его куда нужно

    }
}
```

Запустить рабочего:

```
php artisan queue:work redis --queue=processing
```

Создать задачу:

```
ProcessUploadedFile::dispatch($fullPathToUploadedFile)->onQueue('processing');
```

Если захотите разделить обработку на несколько этапов, смотрите [цепь задач](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-chaining)

**Не забудьте настроить очередь (redis, к примеру выше) в настройках.**